# how to programaticly disable some times from input type time

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is possible to disable some times from time picker dialog and change background color of selected time.

```
<input type="time" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> Include attempt(s): [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i don't think it is is possible with the default html input, but you can use a library

Answer (score -1):

**In the example, between 09:00 and 18:00 is selected. If another time zone is selected, the form will fail to submit.**

**For the selected value to come, it is sufficient to enter the value value.**

```
<input type="time" min="09:00" max="18:00" required value="11:10">
```